# How to change the layout of a section class with Tailwind CSS based on viewport width?

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I am struggling with the execution of the following idea and would be really glad to get support:

I have created this article preview section which looks great on small screen (mobile) devices:

[image: Article preview]

```html
<section class="w-full md:w-2/3 flex flex-col items-center px-3">
    <article class="w-full flex flex-col shadow my-4">
    <div class="bg-white flex flex-col justify-start p-6">
            <div class="max-w"><a
                    href="#>"
                    class="text-blue-700 hover:text-blue-500 text-sm font-bold uppercase pb-4">#Tag&nbsp;#Tagg&nbsp;#TAGGG</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#"
                class="text-3xl font-bold hover:text-gray-700 pb-4">Article title</a>
            <p href="#" class="text-sm pb-3">By <a href="#" class="font-semibold hover:text-gray-800">author</a>, published at 12.03.2021
            </p>
        <div class="aspect-w-16 aspect-h-9">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1614730321146-b6fa6a46bcb4?crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&fit=max&fm=jpg&ixid=MnwxMTc3M3wwfDF8c2VhcmNofDIzfHxlYXJ0aHxlbnwwfHx8fDE2Mjc1NTc2ODI&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&w=2000">
        </a>
        </div>
            <a href="#"
                class="pb-6 prose max-w-none">Here comes a teaser or an excerpt of the article text...</a>
            <div><a href="#"
                class="uppercase hover:font-bold text-gray-700 hover:text-black"><mark>Read more…&nbsp;<i
                    class="fas icon-arrow-right"></i></mark></a></div>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

Now I want to change the layout on bigger screens (`md: = @media (min-width: 768px) &`) to this one:

[image: Mockup for big screens]

Sadly my knowledge is too limited to achieve my idea. What needs to be added/changed to achieve it?

[Link to the Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/k65tvYzxmE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method to achieve this would be having 2 images and hiding 1 of them based on the screensize.

So on big screens you would hide the left aligned image with these classes:

```
hidden md:block
```

`md:block` overwrites `hidden`.

And the inline image gets hidden on big screens:

```
md:hidden
```

[I made you a playground (also cleaned up unneccesary classes and tags a bit)](https://play.tailwindcss.com/DyE5lIdmXj)

I left aligned the image with `grid` and `grid-cols`. There definitely are other methods to do this.